# when Azure blob storage is mounted using blob fuse on linux the mount size is 7.8GB , how to increase the initial mount size to 2 TB

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

when blob is mounted using blob fuse on linux the mount size is 7.8GB , how to increase the initial mount size to 2 TB

Comment: If you are using a [ramdisk for the temporary path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-how-to-mount-container-linux#optional-use-a-ramdisk-for-the-temporary-path), can you try mount via `sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=2T tmpfs /mnt/ramdisk`?

Comment: @NancyXiong Please post your inputs as an answer so it helps others in the community having similar asks. Thanks!